# I am looking for software/command to control IrDA

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, irda

Just like hcitool controls bluetooth, I am looking for command or software(I prefer to use console so I can make scripts) to control IrDA port. Is there any software/command that can do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IRDA is supported on ubuntu, but many individual hardware implementations are not. Install the the irda-utils package and issue the included findchip command to see if you are in luck..

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install irda-utils
sudo findchip -v
```

If you luck out, you might find the following link useful...

http://blogs.fsfe.org/stefan.a/2011/05/24/irda_infrared_data_transfer_on_ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

IrDA-utils is what you are looking for. See here for more info and usage: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Infrared-HOWTO/infrared-howto-s-software.html#AEN132

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

the projects official webpage can be found [here](http://irda.sourceforge.net/download.html) as already mentioned, IrDA is not supported by many hardwaretypes anymore, as it has been replaced mostrly by bluetooth.
But the project's webpage offers you a summary of all available driverpackages for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IrDA project on sourceforge including How-to.

- http://irda.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html
- http://tuxmobil.org/howto_linux_infrared.html

Very much depends what you want to do with IrDA, so hope this project helps.